# LUIS , fetching user response from bot

Tags: node.js, nlp, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have build bot integrated with LUIS , An intent by name "Order" is getting captured and dialogue get triggered successfully . I want to know how to capture the User's input .
I am not allowed to use prompt because the intent recognition is happening and then accordingly dialogue gets initiated .

Looking forward to help me in capturing User input .

Example" User said : Looking for my status of my last order .

order is intent .

matched 80% -------> order dialogue started .

```js
var builder = require('botbuilder');
module.exports = function(bot) {
    // Make sure you add code to validate these fields
    var luisAppId = process.env.LuisAppId;
    var luisAPIKey = process.env.LuisAPIKey;
    var luisAPIHostName = process.env.LuisAPIHostName || 'westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com';

    const LuisModelUrl = 'https://' + luisAPIHostName + '/luis/v2.0/apps/' + luisAppId + '?subscription-key=' + luisAPIKey;

    // Create a recognizer that gets intents from LUIS, and add it to the bot
    var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(LuisModelUrl);
    bot.recognizer(recognizer);

    // Add a dialog for each intent that the LUIS app recognizes.
    // See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-recognize-intent-luis 

    bot.dialog('OrderDialog',
    function (session) {
        session.send("this is order LUIS segment, try to fetch User input " 
        }
    ).triggerAction({
        matches: 'Order'
    })
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking how to prompt the user for input inside of the 'OrderDialog' intent at the point where you currently include `session.send()`?

Comment: No , Sorry but I refine my question , I am looking more into capturing whole input given by user . example if (step1) user asked bot -"I want to know my order status" in the statement order is intent , once intent is recognized by LUIS it  will bring orderDialogue . I want to capture whole statement asked by user in step1.

Answer (score 0):

```js
bot.dialog('OrderDialog',
    function (session) {
        console.log("session value capturing==============>",session.message.text);
        }
        );
```